# Visual Studio 2012 constantly complaining that a file has been modified outside of the source editor

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am working on a parser, using the parser generator `ANTLR` in `Visual Studio`.  Naturally, `ANTLR` is continually regenerating certain files.  Every single time it does this, VS has a popup saying:

> The file has been modified outside of the source editor.
>    Do you want to reload it?

The answer I want is always `Yes to All`.

Is there any way to tell `Visual Studio`to always assume I want to reload auto-generated files, without prompting?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Click Tools then options then under the environment node on the left choose documents then check the box that says `Auto-load changes, if saved`:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work with the CUDA projects I have which are generated from CMake.

Comment: I don't see this option in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition. Instead I see `Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes`

Comment: @kilkfoe Did you manage to fix the problem? Also can't see the option - it appears to have changed name during the versions

Comment: No, I have not found a solution, it's still bothering me every time I open the terminal and run git commands like checking out another branch

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio's internal editor and you know that nobody else is editing the file, you might be wondering why that happens. In my case, I realized I was working on a *continuously backed-up network folder*, that's why the file got *re-saved* every time I made a change on it and saved. So, if you can move your file to a local, *not-backed-up* folder, that might also solve this problem.